# What's the difference between serialize and encode?

Tags: symfony, serialization

I'm using [Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Serializer.html), and I'm not sure what the difference between the `serialize` and `encode` methods is. They have identical signatures, and in practice they seem to give identical output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **serialize** method of the Symfony Serializer is a wrapper on its **encode**  method. Note that you can call the **encode** method separately. The serialize method can call the **normalize** method before the **encode** method depending on the fact that the requested encoder (eg: json) needs normalization or not. 
If you intend to do a JSON serialization, the **encode** method of the serializer will eventually call  **json_encode** PHP native method. And this method performs a serialization in fact...

For example, if you look into the [jsonSerialize](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) method of the **jsonSerializable** native class of PHP, you can read in the description:

> Serializes the object to a value that can be serialized natively by json_encode().

So, at least, in the case of the JSON format, we can say that encoding is serializing in fact but in lower level.

If you call the **encode** method directly without using the **serialize** method, you will serialize your data into the expected format but will not take benefits of the **normalize** process if needed.

Comment: I think the wording of this answer could be a lot clearer, but it does answer the question. The reason I was seeing identical behavior from `serialize` and `encode` was because the object I was calling them on was a `JsonSerializable`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the official **[docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)**, serializing involves two phases: normalizing and encoding. Normalizing converts input data into array, while encoding crunches that array down to desirable format (be it `JSON`, `XML` or something else).

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't explain `serialize` and `encode` might give the same output.